# Why are Managed Beans not loaded in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jsf, javabeans

I created a JSF 2 web application with facelets. The libs for JSF where stored at tomcat/lib, to share it between several applications. I thought maybe it would be better to store the libs inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of the application, to get the application more independent from server configurations.

Now when I start tomcat via eclipse, the managed beans are loaded and working. But when I start tomcat directly / standalone the managed beans are not loaded automatically. I used

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped / @RequestScoped
```

annotations to declare classes as managed beans.

Why is this?
What can I do to fix it?

I don't use any faces-config.xml file yet.

Thanks in advance.

edited:

Maybe this helps to see whats going on:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /Artikel.xhtml @12,108 value="#{artikelBackingBean.nameFilterPattern}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'artikelBackingBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1008)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:934)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1189)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:691)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1080)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1180)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Did you remove the JSF libs from `Tomcat/lib`?

Comment: Ugh nobody here speaks English.

Answer (score 4):

The jsf find beans in WEB-INF/classes, when started with tomcat:run the classes isn´t this location.

Use mvn tomcat:run-war, worked for me.

Comment: How do you know that OP is using Maven? Neither the OP's current question nor any of OP's previously asked questions indicate that he's using Maven or is at least in some way familiar with it.

Comment: A simple JSF project run with MAven Tomcat 7 plugin using tomcat7:run is failing to detect @ManagedBean annotation and throwing PropertyNotFound exception. But working fine with mvn:tomcat7:run-war.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign that the webapp is using JSF 1.x instead of JSF 2.x. The configurator of JSF 1.x does not recognize `@ManagedBean` annotations which will cause that they're not loaded/initialized automagically without the need for `faces-config.xml`.

I would suspect some collision in the version of the JSF libraries used. Scan the entire classpath for JSF JAR files and use some zip/rar tool to determine the included `MANIFEST.MF` file for the actual JSF version. The classpath includes `Tomcat/lib`, `JRE/lib/*` and `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and found the solution was the true attribute in my maven-war-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin-war-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So setting this to false (false) solved my issue.

I blogged about it as well:
http://www.baselogic.com/blog/development/java-javaee-j2ee/propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable-identifier-patientbean-resolved-to-null

Answer (score 0):

Add `META-INF/context.xml` file to web root folder and use `run-war`. You can put an empty `Context` tag inside the file.